# How to send SMS on real device phone number? not on emulator

Tags: android

I need your help. I want to send SMS on real device on its contact number not on emulator. I tried this code but its working on emulator not on real device. can anybody tell me about any API or any other library to send SMS on real device phone number. Please if don't want to help me then don't make it duplicate please 
This is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button sendBtn;
EditText txtphoneNo;
EditText txtMessage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
  txtphoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
  txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

  sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View view) {
        sendSMSMessage();
     }
  });
 }
 protected void sendSMSMessage() {
  Log.i("Send SMS", "");
  String phoneNo = txtphoneNo.getText().toString();
  String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();

  try {
     SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
     smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  } 

  catch (Exception e) {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
  }
```

it does not throws any exception or any other error but sms is being only on emulator not on real device. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you imported the correct `SmsManager` class? How long is the message you're sending?

Comment: I tried any type of message. only "Hi" word but its not working @MikeM.

Comment: can you please tell me that is there any API or other library to send sms on real phone number (contact number) or can be sent through smsManager class? @MikeM. thanks

Comment: That is the API to send SMS on Android. Make sure you're sending to a valid phone number.

Comment: @MikeM. its wokring now but in status bar it is showing sender name "mine" . how to change it with App name

Comment: That's not a direct result of the `SmsManager` API. Possibly another app is issuing that notification - like your default SMS app - or it might be a functionality of the particular OS you're using. You probably can't change it, but you'd first have to figure out what's doing it to be certain.